# Retrieving 1st day of month using NSCalendar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nscalendar

I execute following snippet of code:

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *comp = [gregorian components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]]; 
[comp setDay:1]; 

NSDate *firstDayOfMonthDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:comp];
```

The Value of firstDayOfMonthDate is = 30-4-2011 but excpeted is 1-5-2011 i.e I want first date of month of any specified date.
But it gives me the last date of the previous month.

thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the value of [NSDate date]?

Comment: I also think that it is timeZone thing.But I also tried by setting 2 different time zone values : 1. timeZoneWithAbbreviation:EST it works but gives probelm if app is run in US.I m developing code in India (Asia) 2. systemTimeZone : Gives date  30-4-2011 .

Comment: You have to use UTC, please look at my answer.

Comment: Very similar problem to: [IOS: problem with NSDate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887299/ios-problem-with-nsdate)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add

```
[gregorian setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
```

after initializing your NSCalendar.

`[NSDate date]` will return a date in the UTC timezone, well an absolute interval since January 1, 2001 00:00 GMT, but the NSCalendar has its timeZone set to the default timezone which may not be UTC.

UTC is the "same" as UTC, a quote from wikipedia:

> In casual use, when fractions of a
>   second are not important, Greenwich
>   Mean Time (GMT) can be considered
>   equivalent to UTC or UT1. Saying "GMT"
>   often implies either UTC or UT1 when
>   used within informal or casual
>   contexts. In technical contexts, usage
>   of "GMT" is avoided; the unambiguous
>   terminology "UTC" or "UT1" is
>   preferred.[3]

Comment: thanks.It worked.But i m not getting two point that 1. Why it doest work when I set [gregorian setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]]; 2. What points should be considered while using NSDate & NSCalendar in application so that this kind of problems is not faced again.